# How to connect multiple textures in the one in SDL2?

Tags: c++, c, image, textures, sdl

In my code I want to connect (or combine) multiple `SDL_Texture` or array into one `SDL_Texture` which will contain images each put down under another.

It may look just like this

```
SDL_Texture* t1 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(my_renderer, someSurface);
SDL_Texture* t2 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(my_renderer, someOtherSurface);
//Some SDL code manipulations to make one SDL_Texture wich contains t1 and t2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: C or C++ ? can't be both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to  create your target_texture or something like this:

```
SDL_Texture* target_tex =SDL_CreateTexture(.....); //Add arg according to you
SDL_SetRenderTarget(my_renderer, target_tex);

SDL_Texture* t1 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(my_renderer, someSurface);
SDL_Texture* t2 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(my_renderer, someOtherSurface);
.
.
.
.
SDL_RenderCopy(my_renderer, t1, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RenderCopy(my_renderer, t2, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RenderCopy(my_renderer, t3, NULL, NULL);
.
.
.
SDL_SetRenderTarget(my_renderer, NULL);
SDL_RendererPresent(my_renderer);


SDL_RenderClear(my_renderer);
SDL_RenderCopy(my_renderer, target_tex, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RendererPresent(my_renderer);
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped.